# Photoshop's Save For Web and Devices option works for Android icon design?

Tags: android, user-interface, icons, photoshop

I want to create android icon for all resolutions (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi) using photoshop. When I create an icon for hdpi using 240 resolution and save it using **Save For Web and Devices** option, it reduces icon's resolution to 72.

No matter what resolution I select for creating icon but resultant icon will be of 72 resolution.

My question is can we use such icon (with resultant resolution of 72) in android applications ?

How these icons affect the overall application UI as compared to normal save as option (File -> save as -> png)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you did not see before, there are some tools available to generate icon set directly. You can have a look to this online tool: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html. An icon set generator is also available in Eclipse with Android plugins.

Comment: Thanks for Quick response! I tried using Google icon generator(as you suggested), it also create all icons(x/h/m/l dpi) with 72 resolution.

Comment: Only the hdpi folder contains a 72 resolution, the others: mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi contain images with resolution of 48, 96 and 144 respectively. How big is the image you upload at the beginning?

Comment: I tried in two ways. 1) I uploaded an image of resolution 480 and size 66x66. But resultant icon using Google icon generator in all folders(x/h/m/l) is having same 72 resolution.   (2) Secondly, I used clip art option instead of uploading image on Google icon generator page, but again result was same.

Comment: If you upload an image of 66px, you will not be able to get bigger ones with the generator. If you need icons until xhdpi, your image's size must be at least 96px. Have a look a this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use this icons with 72 dpi on Android devices :)
Photoshop is not able to save an image with resolution higher than 72 dpi. But you must understand a difference between size of image with resolution >72dpi and an actual size.

Please take a look at this image: http://www.mediafire.com/view/tmy5omyibnoxuv7/photoshop-dpi.jpg. As you can see both of pictures have the same actual size - 512x512px, but different document size. When you will export this image you will get 512px image.

But you can convert the image to lower or higher resolution, you just need to un-check the checkbox "Resample image". If you leave this checkbox as checked, the image will change its actual size.

Hope this will help you a bit :)

-- Alex